# Simple INSERT query creates 2 records instead of one

Tags: php, mysql

You've got a simple table, a simple INSERT query and a quite weird result. Instead of a single empty query, the second `mysql_query` call creates 2 empty records. Why?

```
mysql_query("
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` SET `users`.`id` = NULL");
```

Note: Running the query in phpMyAdmin gives the expected result - creates a single record.

Edit:

Adding the following `mysql_query` call to the beginning of the snippet fixes it.

```
mysql_query("DROP TABLE `users`");
```

Edit:

Turned out the problem is related to mod_rewrite ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683705/requesting-a-file-on-a-server-executes-index-php)).

Comment: Are you certain that the PHP script is being invoked only once?

Comment: Are you certain you're not seeing a row from a previous run? If the table exists, it's not truncated. (BTW, can't repro.)

Comment: @Mat, I don't know, I used to drop the table before I run the script. Adding a drop table query call to the beginning of the script, though, fixes the problem. Hm...

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: what's your problem then exactly?

Comment: @Mat, I drop the table through phpMyAdmin, I run the script (without the "DROP TABLE" part) and I get a table with 2 records instead of one.

Comment: That is your issue as if the table is there the create will now run!

Comment: @Lee, I know. The table is not there though. Anyway, thanks for the feedback, I'll try to isolate the problem further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you run this script twice.

The first time script does:

1. Create table.
2. Insert row

The secont time:

1. Tries to create table, but you get an error because table already exists, and nothing happens
2. Insert second row

Try to add this line to check errors - 'echo mysql_error()."\n";'. For example -

```
mysql_query("
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");

echo mysql_error()."\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (NULL)`