# Requests to existing files execute index.php

Tags: php, apache

I use the following .htaccess code to enable friendly URLs in a website.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

The code works fine with a small exception. When I request a file in the browser (i.e. an image), the browser loads it (as I would expect), but along with that index.php gets executed.

I wonder why.

Comment: What do you mean about `along with that index.php executes in the background.`? can you describe more?

Comment: Look at `access.log` and make sure that ONLY ONE url with image is requested

Comment: @Gajahlemu, I mean that the code in index.php executes. If the code creates a folder, I'll have a folder. If it creates a DB table, I'll have a table.

Comment: do what @zerkms said, what its look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the browser was making `GET /favicon.ico` requests and since there was no file with that name on the server, based on the rules in the `.htaccess` file, the requests were redirecting to `/index.php`.